# Page as Archive page

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm having some trouble understanding the logic, I'll try to explain.

Let's say I want to have a Video section. This is how I (want to) do it.

- I make a custom post type called "Videos";
- I make a template to show the video items, call it tpl-videos.php;
- I make a normal page called "Videos", and select the tpl-videos.php as my page template;

Ofcourse, this works, UNLESS you are using some kind of pagination, let's say PagNavi. Whenever I go to page 2, I get an error 404. Reason being: my CPT has the same name as my page.

So I have to change one of them, wich I don't want, 'cause that's weird. If I do that, it will most likely be "Video-items" as CPT, and "Videos" as page. But that's not what I want for my URL's: That will make site.com/videos/video-items/my-video-item, but I want 
site.com/videos/my-video-item.

The correct way is making an archive-videos.php. But, with an archive page I cannot take advantage of the normale page stuff, like Metaboxes, Thumbnails etc etc.

Is there a way to make archive pages behave as pages, without making custom options for each archive page?

**Edit:** There was a misunderstanding regarding my use of Blog as a CPT. Blog can be anything: videos, galleries, whatever. Question updated.

Comment: Can you not just call it something else? 'blog-entry' perhaps. Also it seems a bit odd to have 'blog' as a custom post type when you have all the functionality you would need with 'posts'.

Comment: I use the posts cpt for News. Blog is another section.

Answer (score 2):

The [WordPress Template Hierarchy for custom post type archive index pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display) provides the solution.

Simply create a template file, named `archive-{post-type}.php` - which in your case would be `archive-blog.php`. WordPress will create the archive index automatically (provided you set `'has_archive' => true` in your `register_post_type()` call), will use the `archive-blog.php` automatically, and pagination will work out of the box.

> The correct way is making an archive-blog.php. But, with those pages I cannot take advantage of the normale page stuff, like Metaboxes, Thumbnails etc etc.

Why not? For Featured Images, simply enable support for post-thumbnails for your CPT, in your `register_post_type()` call. For metaboxes: what metaboxes do you want to use for your CPT? For a custom post meta box, that's as easy as adding an `add_meta_box()` call, and changing `$posttype` to `blog`.

> So I have to change one of them, wich I don't want, 'cause that's weird. If I do that, it will most likely be "Blog-items" as CPT, and "Blog" as page. But that's not what I want for my URL's.

And if all you're trying to do is use an `/blog` endpoint for your blog posts index, just use a Static Front Page, create a static page named "Blog", and then assign it as the page for posts via `Settings -> Reading`. No custom post type required.

Comment: I may have mistyped some things. I know I can use thumbnails and metaboxes for the posts inside the Blog CPT, I actually meant the Blog page itself (the page wich displays all the blogitems). This is the archive-page, but I can't use the page functionality on them.

Comment: What specific *page* (i.e. *static page*) functionality do you need/want to use on your CPT archive index page?

Comment: Well, everything the normal pages also have. For example, I have a quotes metabox, a header slider metabox wich I want to use on all available pages. (I don't want to make seperate options pages for each archive). I think it's not gonna work though.. CPT's cannot have the same name as a page if you wanna use the %postname% permalink setting, am I right?